# Is there something like "callable" in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In python, I could use "callable" to check if a variable could be called or not. like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def test():
    print "hello world"

a = test
if callable(a):
    a()
```

so in this way, I can tell that a is a function, not an instance variable.
But in ruby, the braces could be omitted, so for me, when I called it, I cannot tell if it is a function or instance variable. Is there some method to check if the variable is a function or instance variable at runtime?

Comment: You can use respond_to? http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/respond_to%3F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. `defined?` gives you what is being called.

```
a = 1
def a; end
b = 1
def c; end

defined? a   # => "local-variable"
defined? a() # => "method"
defined? b   # => "local-variable"
defined? c   # => "method"
```

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is not allowed in ruby out of the box. This is because parentheses might be omitted in function calls and ruby parser has no chance to understand that you are to call “*callable*” rather than just address it. The easiest workaround might be:

```
▶ λ = ->(param) { puts param }
#⇒ #<Proc:0x00000004e93050@(pry):7 (lambda)>
▶ λ.call(5) if λ.respond_to? :call
#⇒ 5
```

There is a specific corner case, [ruby blocks](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas). Everything, that responds to `to_proc` method, might be passed as code block to any method, that accepts code blocks, and the block will be called implicitly.

E.g.:

```
▶ [1,2,3].each &λ
#⇒ 1
#⇒ 2
#⇒ 3
```

Comment: I agree, but want to point out that due to Ruby's duck typing there is no way to guarantee that an object that responds to :call is what we think it is and not just some class with a method that is named :call by coincidence.  Perhaps you would want only things that either are themselves `Proc`'s, or have a `to_proc` method on them?

Comment: To contradict myself now, that might not be such a great idea.  Now that Ruby has `to_proc` defined on symbols (for use in Hash enumerable methods, I think), any symbol will respond to `to_proc`:   `:x.to_proc`
 => `#<Proc:0x007f82b40de100(&:x)>`

Comment: @KeithBennett as far, as I understood, python checks kinda same thing inside `callable`, smth like `__call__` or like that. So I tried to be as close to the OP as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, a variable is callable, if it responds to `#call`.

```rb
def callable(obj)
  obj.respond_to? :call
end
```